# main.js:114 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'incart' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopping-cart

i've made an array for my shopping cart where the products are with tag,price,incart,name and im trying to change them in the following code.

```
      function setItems(product)
{
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log("My cartItems are", cartItems);

    if (cartItems != null)
    {
        if (cartItems[product.tag] == undefined)
        {
            cartItems = 
            {
                ...cartItems,
                [product.tag]: product 
            }
        }

        cartItems[product.tag].incart += 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        product.incart = 1;
        cartItems = 
        {
        [product.tag]: product
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is `product`? Please show us your complete code, or at least a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: property of function

Answer (score 0):

product.tag is prob not defined, check where ever you call setItems();

```js
if (cartItems[product.tag] == undefined) {
    cartItems = {
        ...cartItems,
        [product.tag]: product
    }
}
```

change to this for better code

```js
if (!cartItems[product.tag]) {
    cartItems[product.tag] = product;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!